# Как убрать ограничения с таблицы posgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Создал таблицу в posgresql, наблюдаю такую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитал что это связанно с правами доступа, я создал роль, этой роле присвоил право вносить изменение в бд, но я не могу понять как подключиться к бд используя эту роль, пробывал вписать в 'user' но это не правильно, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: 1. не надо смотреть на картинки, надо выполнять SQL запросы и смотреть возвращаемые ошибки, что бы точно понимать что не так. 2. Роль надо назначить пользователю https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/sql-grant (см. "GRANT для ролей" и до конца статьи)

Comment: 1. Ошибок не возвращается в этом вся и соль. 2. Если можно решить без ролей я только рад, я раньше пользовался этой бд но не через pgAdmin, тут первый раз создал таблицу и вот такие замочки появились, гуглил ничего найти не могу, единственное что нашел что может быть проблема в ролях

Comment: Если insert в таблицу проходит значит прав точно хватает. А замочки лишь значат что pgAdmin не может сам писать в то, что вывел на экран. Причин может быть множество, например то что на экране сформировано выборкой из нескольких таблиц и разумеется он не понимает как писать сразу в несколько таблиц, или среди выбранных колонок (или вообще в таблице) нет первичного ключа и он не знает как уникально идентифицировать запись и соответственно и работать с ней нормально не может

Comment: Спасибо, я действительно не совсем корректный запрос написал, он не вносил данные в бд и не выдавал ошибок